# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject

Try to create a Parse bases iOS application that saves object in background using a "Share Button" and this code:

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender
{
    if (self.chosenImageView.image)
    {
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.chosenImageView.image);
        PFFile *photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:imageData];
        PFObject *photo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Photo"];
        photo[@"image"] = photoFile;
        photo[@"whoTook"] = [PFUser currentUser];
        photo[@"title"] = self.titleTextField.text;
        [photo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
        {
            if (!succeeded)
            {
                [self showError];
            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [self showError];
    }
    [self clear];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

Getting the "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'" Error.

Please Help......

Comment: try to debug or insert constant and use break points in which key value you are getting error which object you are inserting is getting nil.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty fundamental part of [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) (regardless of your use of Parse or not).  Please review Apple's documentation on [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html), [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html), and [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html).

In this particular case, one of these values: `photoFile`, `[PFUser currentUser]`, or `self.titleTextField.text` is `nil`.

You should check your input for validity, like so:

```
if (photoFile != nil) {
    photo[@"image"] = photoFile;
} else {
    // handle the case where 'photoFile' doesn't exist.
}
```

Comment: I've tried the suggestions...Now it seems as if my PFObject Classes aren't being saved or created in Parse at all.  Any suggestions???

Comment: unfortunately I don't know any more about parse.

Comment: I finally got it...drove me crazy..  instead of..
        PFFile *photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:imageData];
        it should be........ 
        PFFile *photoFile = [PFFile fileWithName:self.titleTextField.text data:imageData];
    PFObject *photo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Photo"];  PFFiles need both explicit name and data sources.